# How to check against a Select statement Returning multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using an IF Statement to check if results from a select statement = 'N'
However the select statement returns multiple rows, Therefore breaking the IF Statement

I've tried to store results in a variable:

`Declare @SENT bit;
SET @SENT = (SELECT AlrdySent FROM  DeliveryNotesNotMatchingSO)
IF @SENT = 'N'`

```sql
    INSERT INTO DeliveryNotesNotMatchingSO
    ([Docnum],
    [AlrdySent])
    Select 
    t1.DocNum as [DocNum],
    'N' as [AlrdySent]
    from miro.dbo.DLN1 t0 
    join miro.dbo.odln t1 on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry
    where day(t1.DocDate) = day(getdate())
    and month(T1.DocDate) = month(getdate())
    and year(T1.DocDate) = year(getdate())
    and t0.BaseEntry is null

    ---Statement in Question
IF (SELECT AlrdySent FROM  DeliveryNotesNotMatchingSO) = 'N' 
BEGIN
---CODE HERE
```

I expect the IF Statement to execute for each result in the select statement, guess I need to do this row by row somehow?

Is there perhaps a better way of logically checking the value of AlrdySent?

Comment: What is the logic which happens after `BEGIN` ?

Comment: The answer might depend on what your actions are for those records that are `N`. 99% of the times, you **don't** need to cycle through row by row and can use set-based approaches that directly use your `N` as a filtering condition.

Comment: Hi there, Records are Emailed Out through a SP, and then the table is updated to set AlrdySent to 'Y' As The emails have been sent out. The above code works fine if there is only one record,

Answer (score 2):

This is the 1% of the cases where you actually need a cursor to cycle records, since you have to send emails through an SP (I assume that works mail by mail).

A [CURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an object that allows you to cycle through a set of rows, a row at a time. You can use the following simple cursor example:

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @AdditionalParameter VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE MailingCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        D.ID,
        D.AdditionalParameter
    FROM
        DeliveryNotesNotMatchingSO AS D
    WHERE
        D.AlrdySent = 'N'

OPEN MailingCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MailingCursor INTO @ID, @AdditionalParameter

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- While the last fetched row was successfully fetched
BEGIN

    EXEC dbo.uspSendMail
        @Input = @ID,
        @Recipient = @AdditionalParameter

    UPDATE D SET
        AlrdySent = 'Y',
        SentDate = GETDATE()
    FROM
        DeliveryNotesNotMatchingSO AS D
    WHERE
        D.ID = @ID -- Assumming its a PK

    FETCH NEXT FROM MailingCursor INTO @ID, @AdditionalParameter

END

CLOSE MailingCursor
DEALLOCATE MailingCursor
```

Comment: Thanks EzLo. I appreciate the response. Let me give this a go